# Blocked loading mixed active content Mozilla Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, warnings

I am working on HTML template and facing a new issue with Mozilla Browser. I am getting these warnings in my console
Error::

> Blocked loading mixed active content
>   “http://site_url/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0”
>
> Blocked loading mixed active content
>   “http://site_url/assets/fonts/icofont.ttf?v=1.0.0-beta”

Check Screen shot::

[image]

I read about Mozilla new security changes, and try to not use mixed content. Now my template didn't have any https://.... url . I included a fonts like this:

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:300,400,500,500i,600,600i,700,900" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GoogleAPIKey' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How to resolve these errors.

Answer (score 4):

Add this code in html head tag

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

Comment: I already tried this before, but after applying this , my page style is not working, most of the css and js library loading is failed after applying this.

Comment: your site is http or https?

Comment: My site is with http

Comment: Did you try with CDN link. not download in your local.

Comment: I am using Snazzy maps in my html template, If I am commenting map iframe code , then it doesn't show any error. Snazzy map loads google api, marker js with https request. But I am confused because it shows fonts are blocked. after commenting map iframe code , there is no error on page. But I want this styled map in my contact us html template

Comment: I downloaded these fonts to local. I didn't used font CDN link.

Comment: share the Snazzy maps js library link?

Comment: You can create your account here https://snazzymaps.com/ and generate styled map using snazzy map. It will generate iframe code, you can use directly this in your html template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173793/discussion-between-archana-and-george).

Comment: @Vel, I am also facing this issue but in different style, I have written an utility (small rest api) running on client machine, when i try to this our actual production environment (along with https and http) it works , but when it try to hit from older version firefox or any browser, then http works but https not.  We can not update our browser . Can you help me to fix this ?

Comment: Blocked loading mixed active content "http://localhost:9999/ab/printer/print"[Learn More]

Comment: and what if you dont want to upgrade insecure requests? how do I just allow them?